# Cannot assign sh to variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to inject they globally available functions to my lib. But I cannot assign the `sh` function to a variable. Why isn't this possible?

```
// var/testFunc.groovy
def call() {
  // works
  def dockerLib = docker
  def dockerLib2 = this.docker
  // fails
  def shLib = sh
  def shLib2 = this.sh
}
```

Comment: `docker` is a global variable, `sh` is a step. Can you try `steps.sh`?

Comment: I suppose you know about the Jenkins Shared Library HowTo? They tell to use the this pointer of the script as an argument to your class‘s constructor, store it in some class member var and the use that var like ‘script.sh’

Comment: [Here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps) is @JoergS solution in the official jenkins docs with some examples.

Comment: Thx for the hints. Yes I know about the shared lib docs. I also have a simple workaround (e.g. for sh: `shellCall = { cmd -> sh cmd}`). But still I don't understand, why this is not possible. I'm fairly new to Groovy.